# Sending \t in NSString IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I am currently working on an app that connects to custom server using NSStream.  Once connected the app allows for user input via a textfield.  In order for the server to recognize an incoming command a \t needs to be first and then the string from something like self.inputField.text.

I have everything working up to this point as far as opening/closing of sockets, sending/receiving etc.

The problem is my sent string looks like so: \tSOMECOMMAND but the \t is not being interpreted as a tab but as string '\tSOMECOMMAND'.  How can I prepend a \t (tab) to the text in my input field?

As always thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you sending the string? How do you add the tab to the string?

Comment: Are you sure the debugger isn't just showing the tab as a "\t" when you print out the string? How are you sending the "\t"? As a string literal in code or some other way?

Comment: It looks like I have the problem corrected.  I do not see why I didn't see this before but my tab was actually appended behind my string instead of in front... /sigh.   Oversight on my part indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't require the user to add the tab character as it's counter-intuitive, easy to forget and an implementation detail they don't need to know about.

In your controller object:

- Get the string from the text field.
- Prepend the tab character.
- Send the string to the server.

Answer (score 1):

A user typing a backslash and a 't' is not necessarily the same as an escape sequence for a tab. 
Those will be sent as two literal characters. 
Your code needs to identify that escape sequence string and replace the string with a tab character. That's what the compiler does to an escape sequence when it is found within delimiters within which it expects there might be an escape sequence.

Comment: Well, a semantic distinction. In the proper context it could be said that is.